# looking for Number of Members in each country whose preference game is set to NES

Tags: oracle

SQL Number of Members in each country whose preference game is set to NES

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
COUNT(AUD)  COUNT(EUR)  COUNT(IND)  COUNT(LAO)  COUNT(USA)  COUNT(ZWE)  
    3           2           0           0       2           1
```

Here is the SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a15ec9f/3

Comment: you tagged sql server oracle and your sample data is mysql, so whoch excatly is it

Comment: What do you have so far? Looks like a straight-forward conditional aggregation (pivot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We `pivot`.

```
select *
from   t
pivot(count(MEMBER_ID) for COUNTRY_ID in('AU' as "count(AU)", 'US' as "count(US)", 'LAO' as "count(LAO)", 'IND' as "count(IND)", 'DE' as "count(DE)", 'ZW' as "count(ZW)")) p
```

| count(AU) | count(US) | count(LAO) | count(IND) | count(DE) | count(ZW) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/16GrXMdD)

Comment: How could I add a where clause in that query? The count looks wrong from the expected result.

Comment: @stella2343 I checked manually and the numbers line up with the sample data. Here's an example of how to use a where clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/qA1hmwH5

Comment: There are three tables, I was thinking we need to use WHERE Member.GAME_TYPE= 'NES';   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a15ec9f/3       but in this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/qA1hmwH5 there is only on table where we are doing count

Comment: @stella2343 check this one out: https://dbfiddle.uk/Fc2XDWEE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Member.MemberID, COUNTRY, GAME_TYPE 
FROM MEMBER_TABLE 
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE ON Member.COUNTRY_ID= COUNTRY_TABLE.COUNTRY_ID 
WHERE Member.GAME_TYPE= 'NES';
```